# Insufficient system resources after a week

Tags: windows-server-2003

On our production server we get the following message when we log in after 1 week uptime

> ```
> Windows cannot load the user's profile but has logged you on with the
> ```
>
> default profile for the system.
>
> ```
> DETAIL - Insufficient system resources exist to complete the
> ```
>
> requested service.

*System specs*

Windows 2003 SP 2 32bit
Intel Xeon E5420
8GB RAM
PAE enabled

Our production System has a SQL Server 2005 running (~1.7GB RAM all the time) and the application consists of 40 Java processes consuming ~2.7GB
There are over 3GB of RAM free.

To get rid of the problem temporarily we have to reboot.

Comment: Event ID number(s)? The only reference I'm finding off Microsoft with cursory google-fu points to this issue on Win2K with Symantec Antivirus running. Also, is anything pegged in the process monitoring, like CPU? What does Process Explorer say for interrupt usage, I/O, anything that looks to be thrashing or spinning out of control?

Comment: Are you using the /3GB switch in your boot.ini file? If you are that's the most likely cause of the problem.

Comment: @joeqwerty /3GB is diabled

Comment: @Bart Silverstrim ID is 1505 also there is a second entry that says that the registry can't be loaded (id is 1508) All Cores are at 50% usage max. One Java process uses 2 cores all for itself (but it has done this before the errors showed up)

Comment: In my experience, this has always been caused by a lack of memory.

Comment: @joeqwerty how can this be a lack of memory when there is always more than 3GB free?

Comment: It's not a lack of physical memory, it's a lack of kernel memory. That's why I asked about the /3GB switch. If you use the /3GB switch you limit kernel memory to 1GB which can cause this problem. Since you're not using the /3GB switch then it's not the cause of your problem. I would take a look at the Pool Nonpaged bytes memory counter in perfmon and see where it's at. On a 32bit, unadulterated Windows system with more than 1GB of RAM the Pool Nonpaged bytes is limited to 256MB. The Nonpaged Pool memory is shared by the kernel, device drivers, system PTE's and the file system cache.

Comment: We have been seeing the same problem with a very similar 32bit windows 2003 setup. CPU 5%, Physical Memory 35%, Kernal Paged 124MB, Kernal Nonpaged 100MB and System PTEs > 15000 ... any other metrics to check?

Answer (score 1):

These seem to pertain primarily to Terminal Services, but maybe they could help you here?

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/935649

http://www.brianmadden.com/forums/t/21033.aspx

Comment: i have to try that. thanks.
I'll be able to do that next week (i hope)

Answer (score 1):

I'd be interested to see what would happen with a 64bit OS.

It smacks of possibly being paged/non-paged pool related.